# Get menubar color / dark mode in Monterey

Tags: objective-c, macos

How do we get what the text color (black/white) of the menubar is in Monterey ?

I'm developing an app with a menubar icon, in previous versions of OSX I could determine whether I should be drawing black or white icons by getting dark mode status with this code:

```
- (BOOL )amiindarkmode   {
    
  if (  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"AppleInterfaceStyle"] != nil ) 
  return YES ;
   
     return NO ;
     
}
```

However in OS X. 12.6 (Monterey) the color of the menubar seems independant of dark mode and just flips for day /  night time regardless.

Is there a new variable in OSX 12.6 I need to monitor ?